# Labeling function: format of numbers

Tags: plotting, labeling

I think this will be easy for many of you, but I struggle.

How can I make the label to be n.nn and not this hugely long numbers? See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Ordinarily you should post your code as text rather than as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NumberForm`:

```
LabelingFunction -> (Placed[NumberForm[Last@#1, 2], Above] &)
```

Comment: You might want {2,2} instead of 2 otherwise the very small numbers in the tail will get a bit long and crowded too.

Comment: @flinty True, but then you'll see 0.00 multiple times in the tail. (Of course, labeling small numbers could be suppressed altogether.)